# Add a column to a dataset C#

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to fill datagrid in a WPF app with data fetched from mysql tables. I have 5 tables with the same structure and I need to get last 20 lines from each.

The code below does it good, except one little thing- I need additional column with store name (store variable that is fetched by first query) in each corresponding row.

Please any thoughts where to start!

```
void fillDataTable()
{
    string store;
    string connection = Properties.Settings.Default.sqlconn;
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connection);
    conn.Open();
    string nameQuery = "SELECT `name` FROM `stores`";
    MySqlCommand selectStore = new MySqlCommand(nameQuery, conn);
    MySqlDataReader readName = selectStore.ExecuteReader();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    while (readName.Read())
    {
        store = readName["name"].ToString();
        MySqlConnection conn1 = new MySqlConnection(connection);
        conn1.Open();
        string dataQuery = "SELECT * FROM `"+ store + "` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 20";
        MySqlCommand selecetData = new MySqlCommand(dataQuery, conn1);
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(selecetData);
        da.Fill(ds, "LoadDataBinding");
        conn1.Close();
    }
    salesGrid.DataContext = ds;
    conn.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this (avoiding looping through your datatable to fill your column) :

```
string dataQuery = "SELECT '"+ store + "' AS \"store\",* FROM '"+ store + "' ORDER BY 'id' DESC LIMIT 20";
```

Answer (score 0):

well, you can add any number of columns to your DataTable simply by a code such as this one:

```
ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("ColumnName", Type.GetType("System.String"));
```

**Note**: you need to add the column after you fill the dataset.